# Gazebo-1.6 Update : build probem

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I recently updated drcsim and gazebo to drcsim-2.3 and gazebo-1.6. SInce then I am unable to build controllers. I think it is not able to find the include files.

/home/bharadwajramesh/gazebo_plugin_tutorial/hello_world.cc:1:21: fatal error: gazebo.hh: No such file or directory

What is the problem here, am I missing something or is there something I should do ?

-thanks
Bharadwaj

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/2352/gazebo-1.6-update-:--build-probem/) by [Bharadwaj Ramesh](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/154/bharadwaj-ramesh/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 51 on 2013-04-12

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [skhan](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/266/skhan/) on 2013-04-12**:
are you using ROS along with it?

**Comment by [Bharadwaj Ramesh](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/154/bharadwaj-ramesh/) on 2013-04-12**:
I have the DRCSim-2.3 also installed . I believe the DRCSim has Roc packages with it. So yeah, I do have ros

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I Have it fixed : I deleted all the files inside my build folder. And executed the cmake../ command inside the build forder again and build it. This WORKS. I dont know what it does though. If someone can tell me how it helped... it will be great. Thanks

---

Originally posted by [Bharadwaj Ramesh](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/154/bharadwaj-ramesh/) with karma: 51 on 2013-04-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Ben B](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/136/ben-b/) on 2013-04-12**:
When you run CMAKE, a lot of environment specific information is compiled into your executable files.  So when the contents were made before, it might have created executables that, for instance, were dependent on the file path to the old version of Gazebo. These executables end up in your build folder.  By clearing that out and re-CMAKEing everything, you recreate those executables with the up-to-date paths.